# SonarQube C# Rule CommentRegularExpression => S124 does not work anymore

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am using the C# Plugin 4.0 for Sonar Qube.
Up to Version 3.3 there was rule called `CommentRegularExpression`, which I used to track TODO comments in my Code.
From Version 3.4 and Version 4.0 (My current version) on the rule has changed to S124.
S124 has no possibility to add a regular expression and therefore it does nothing.
I had a look at the `rules.xml` of the source code of the c# plugin and compared it with rule S101 (Class name should comply with a naming convention).
Rule S101 has a param where the user can put in the regular expression.
Rule S124 has no parameters at all, and I guess this is the reason why it can not be configured and it does nothing.

Can you please tell me if this is a bug of not.
If it is not a bug how can I configure the regular expression for the S101?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not cross-post: You've posted the same question on the SonarQube Google group.

This indeed is a bug, for which a ticket has been created to be fixed in the upcoming 4.1 release of the C# plugin: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-540